# Row-wise update in SQL DataAdapter.Update

Tags: c#

I had a problem with `DataAdapter.Update`.

The scenario is this: I have a database table like this

```
Student
(StudentID INT NOT NULL,
 STUDENTNAME NVARCHAR(100),
 STUDENTIdentity    INT DEFAULT 10)
```

And in my `Datatable` I have rows such as

**dsStudent**

```
StudentID   STUDENTNAME STUDENTIdentity 
1           AAA         
2           BBB             20
3           CCC
```

When I am trying to update the student `Datatable` like this

```
ds.Update(dsStudent,"Student");
```

This is working fine. But my `studentidentity` column in the database, inserting NULL values instead of default value 10.

I thought of implementing `OnRowUpdating` event and to change the parameters to achieve the row-wise update statement alteration.

But the problem is this has been implemented in my project already. So do we have any generic solution to do this?

Sample Code where i am trying to update

> ```
>         dr = ds.Tables["Student"].NewRow();
>
>         dr["StudentId"] = 534;
>
>         dr["StudentName"] = "robin";
>
>         ds.Tables["Student"].Rows.Add(dr);
>
>         cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
>
>         da.Update(ds, "Student");
> ```

Comment: I am not able to format my Table Structure while posting question. Could anyone please suggest me on this?

Comment: @Kiran, Thanks a lot for editing, i thought no one will understand my question.. :)

Comment: if we don't update or insert value for `studentidentity` ,it will take default value but you are explicitly updating `studentidentity` value as null,so it will not consider the default value.

Comment: ok in this case, if i add a datarow , by assigning two columns only still i acheive the same problem.. I am not explicitly assigning null value.. the system implicitly taking taking null value which i dont want to do? so can i avoid that

Comment: what do you mean assigning only two columns?will your datarow has two clolumns or three?

Comment: DataRow has 3 columns, but i will assign 2 columns. so that the insert statement has to form insert into student(studentid,studentname) values(34,"CCC") but instead its forming insert into student(studentid,studentname,studentidentity) values(34,"CCC",NULL) Which i dontwant for NULL rows

Comment: when you do update on data table it updates all the columns which it has, irrespective of which rows are assigned.

Comment: Exacty, thats the problem.... how do i overcome this? can i override the update method or in onrowupdating for each row. I cant use stored procedure because i need to rewrite the entie code. I can use selectcommand as "select studentid,studentname from student" but i will miss the actual rows which as student identity data

Comment: Can you show some code ,how you are updating the table?

Comment: Hi i updated my question with sample code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sqlcommandbuilder to generate update command,use your own sql command .

for update:

```
 SqlCommand upCmd = new SqlCommand(
"update emp set Name=@Name, Age=@Age where No=@No",con);
 upCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Name");
 upCmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Age");
 upCmd.Parameters.Add("@No", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "No");
 sqlDa.UpdateCommand = upCmd;
 sqlDa.Update(dSet,"emp");
```

for Insert:

```
 SqlCommand insCmd = new SqlCommand(
 "insert into emp (Name, Age) values(@Name, @Age)",con);
 insCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Name");
 insCmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Age");
 sqlDa.InsertCommand = insCmd;
 sqlDa.Update(dSet,"emp");
```

give your new row values in the parameter values.

try this and let me know/

Answer (score 0):

`DataAdapter.Update` method uses `DataAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText` to speak to database. If you look at the string, you see by default something adequate to:

```
UPDATE [Student]
SET [StudentID] = @StudentID,
    [STUDENTNAME] = @STUDENTNAME,
    [STUDENTIdentity] = @STUDENTIdentity
WHERE
    ...
```

The trouble is in line `[STUDENTIdentity] = @STUDENTIdentity` where command sets explicitly `DBNull` to the column. That's why the default value from the database doesn't work.

See that `DataAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText` is a writable property. Thus the simplest, but not generic solution, is to copy previous, original command text, remove the problematic line and set that modified version back, so then there is:

```
UPDATE [Student]
SET [StudentID] = @StudentID,
    [STUDENTNAME] = @STUDENTNAME
WHERE
    ...
```

After that, STUDENTIdentity will be not updated explicitly and thus the default value from the database will be used.

You should probably update `InsertCommand` too.